# AWS EMR JupyterHub access issue on MacOS Catalina due to Temporary SSL Certificate recognized as "Invalid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-emr, jupyterhub, macos-catalina

After upgrading to MacOS Catalina, I am no longer able to access AWS EMR JupyterHub as the new OS blocks temporary SSL certificates. Found a relevant post on Github but no resolution. Any suggestions?

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2168

Describe the bug:
Temporary Certificates issued when a valid certificate issuance all seem to have the same serial numbers, which in MacOS Catalina causes both Firefox and Chrome to block even allowing access to the sites.

Chrome gives a standard ERR_CERT_INVALID error, and firefox gives a SEC_ERROR_REUSED_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL error

Answer (score 7):

> TL;DR Type `thisisunsafe` on your google chrome page where you're
>   seeing this error and this should let you access the page.

Folks, I was trying to access Jupyter Hub running on AWS EMR using ssh tunneling & foxy proxy but for some reason, I was seeing `ERR_CERT_INVALID` error in Google Chrome. I messed around it but finally, this is a little trick solved my problem.

Type anywhere on google chrome (make sure you're on the page where you are seeing this error) and just type `thisisunsafe` using your keyboard and boom. This will let you access the page that previously giving you trouble with https/ssl.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone having this issue on Mac OS Catalina, you should add the Self-Signed certificate or the revoked certificate to the keychain and then trust it from there. This affects only Chrome. On FireFox and Safari you should not have this issue.

Following tutorial make it easier to understand. https://css-tricks.com/getting-around-revoked-certificate-osx/